# Postgresql Order By Multiple Cascading?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I hope this is a quick question but I can't figure it out. Is there a way to cascade order by in Postgres? For example say I have the following table:

| Name | Staff_ID | Attribute_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Horse | null | 1 |
| Bird | null | 10 |
| Cat | 1 | 8 |
| Dog | 2 | 8 |
| Cat | 1 | 9 |
| Dog | 2 | 9 |

Can I have it return so that the order is by attribute_id asc and then it sorts by staffid when it sees multiple entries in the order and puts nulls first? Such as:

EDIT: Added this in the comments

> I guess ultimately I want to order by Attribute_ID until it sees multiple entries for a staff_id asc and then orders by staff_id before returning to attribute_id

| Name | Staff_ID | Attribute_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Horse | null | 1 |
| Cat | 1 | 8 |
| Cat | 1 | 9 |
| Dog | 2 | 8 |
| Dog | 2 | 9 |
| Bird | null | 10 |

Thank you!

Comment: Description is complex, not sure I got it right. Isn't that Order by staff_id, Attribute_id? Oh not, I saw  you introduce a non-existent value. I don't know where it would come from.

Comment: Hey Cetin I just updated the list to make more sense and be more correct? 

I guess ultimately I want to order by Attribute_ID until it sees multiple entries for a staff_id asc and then orders by staff_id before returning to attribute_id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want all `name`s to be together, based on the minimum attribute id for the name.  That would be:

```
order by min(attribute_id) over (partition by name),
         name,
         attribute_id;
```

Comment: This works, I was messing it up. Thank you so much!